# Placeholder text in html form becomes oddly positioned upon increasing height of text box

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

So I made a form which consists of text inputs, and for one of them, I increased the height of one.

Next thing I see, only the size of the text box increased, but my placeholder text begins at the center and when I click on it, I'm only able to type from the center, and not from the top...

What is going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a text input (`<input type="text">`), it is a single-line input.
Changing its height will not allow for more lines.

Consider using a `<textarea>` instead, as they are multi-line inputs.

http://jsfiddle.net/mkHvK/

Answer (score 0):

If you really feel the need to have the text not centered vertically, use `padding` instead of `height` in your CSS, like so:

```
#text-input {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  /* Instead of height: 30px; */
}
```

Here's a demo at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ejegof/1/edit).

I would however echo the recommended `textarea` answer.